# viewing canvas/bitmap on the fly while debugging in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, bitmap, android-canvas

Is there a way to debug canvas/bitmaps on Eclipse? I was wondering if I could view how the current canvas/bitmap looks when I set a breakpoint at a particular line.

Comment: You can see what you've painted after returning from `paint()` in the emulator. But you probably want to see your Canvas (or the bitmap behind it) growing with each line of code, right?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if I could see the contents of the canvas/bitmap just like watching variable contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Viewing bitmaps while debugging is possible now (though only with Android Studio).

From the [release notes for version 0.8.7](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio087released) (Aug 21, 2014)

> **Bitmap rendering in the debugger**
>
> While debugging, you can now right click on variables in your app that
>   are of type Bitmap, and invoke View Bitmap:
>
> [image]
>
> This will then fetch the associated data from the debugged process and
>   render the bitmap in place in the debugger.
>
> [image]

Comment: As of at least Android 1.3, this option has been removed. Now, View Bitmap can be found in the variables tab to the right of the Bitmap. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31291397/2337925