# Android Studio debugger View Bitmap

Tags: android, android-studio

[image] As of release 0.8.7 of Android Studio there's supposed to be a Bitmap viewer in the debugger. See the release notes here: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio087released

I have 0.8.9 installed and I can't see this option. Has anyone been able to use this? Is there something I need to enable?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

First run your program in debug mode by using <kbd>Shift+F9</kbd> and set a breakpoint right after the bitmap object you want to investigate is created. Once the debugger pauses at the breakpoint hover over the `bitmap` variable and right click and select *View Bitmap* and that's all you need to view it.

[image: View bitmap in debug mode]

Comment: I thought it may have been because I ran my app then attached the debugger, but I initially ran my app through the debugger and same thing...no View Bitmap option. I added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: Are you hovering over the bitmap *variable* or the bitmap you are watching? It looks from your screenshot that you are watching it but you have to use the bitmap variable from the variable list.

Comment: That did it! Thanks brother! I wonder why you can't get to it by watching though :S

Comment: **View Bitmap** is now available inline. Can believe this doesn't have more votes!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was looking for something similar for quite sometime

Answer (score 79):

I'm on Android Studio 1.3 and I didn't find 'View Bitmap' option in the context menu. Turns out that this option now sits right next to every `Bitmap` variable in the debugger's 'Variables' window:

[image]

Comment: Yeah they added that in recently.

Comment: Its available in 1.2.2 too.

Comment: still available in 2.2.1

Comment: Is there a way to save the bitmap from this screen?

Comment: @Ranbeuer screengrab? :P