# View Mat content while debugging

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, mat

I'm coding some image processing algorithms using Android OpenCV and I'm going crazy to debug some parts. Say that my steps are:

1. threshold source image (Mat src) so I get a Mat with the result
   (Mat dst)
2. get objects (Mat objs)
3. get contours (Mat conts)
4. etc.

Is there any way to check the contents of each Mat in debug mode? (apart from "plotting" the image in my device). It would be awesome to see the whole matrix in a table (like in Matlab workspace). Thanks!

Comment: afaik there is a possibility. I've read about it but don't totally remember whether it's only for selected IDEs and/or you need some kind of plugin. Probably @berak knows more.

Comment: see http://opencv.org/image-debugger-plug-in-for-visual-studio.html (googled opencv debug images)

Comment: thanks @Micka , unfortunately I work with android studio and I guess there isn't anything similar

Comment: There's opencv [ccv module](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dcf/tutorial_cvv_introduction.html#gsc.tab=0). No idea if java wrapper exists already

Comment: It seems that the java wrapper does not exist yet. Thanks anyway, I will definitely track its development

Comment: I afraid the best solution is to cast it to bitmap and then use [android studio bitmap dibugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976141/android-studio-debugger-view-bitmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can use OpenCV Image Viewer Plugin, which works with Android Studio. It displays the Mat in IDE with one click while debugging. No need to plot in the device :)

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14371-opencv-image-viewer
[image]

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this plugin