# android:drawing still has opacity after setting "PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR"

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I want to make a hole in a solid colored view but I can't get what I want. I use the following code:

```
my customView extends View{
...

protected void PunchTheView() {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black);
        canvas.drawRect(outerRectangle, paint);


        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        float centerX = getWidth()/2;
        float centerY = (getHeight()/2)-120 ;
        float radius = (getWidth()-(getWidth()/6))/2;  
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, paint);


    }
}
```

and this is the result when I use it; the hole still has some opacity. (note that the root holder has white background)

"I also tried `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT` and  `PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT`
and they didn't help neither

[image])

Comment: whar does `bitmap.getPixel(centerX, centerY)` return?

Comment: I never used this , didn't get the question @pskink

Comment: it returns the 32bit value, what is that value?

Comment: it returns zero @pskink

Comment: so CLEAR works ok as alpha of 0x00000000 is 0

Comment: then what's wrong?? why the white background shows up grey??

Comment: because you have some gray layer behind

Comment: no it's not !! only a white view is beneath it. I uploaded an image of it

Comment: did you try `Layout Inspector`?

Comment: yup. everything's as they should be. guess the problem is with the implementation of the hole, and I have no clue what it is.

Comment: ok then place the breakpoint in `canvas.drawCircle` line, execute that line and see `bitmap` in "Variables" pane: there should be "View bitmap" option on the right side (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27928996/2252830), what do you see when you click on it?